# JTable returning JTable when calling getModel()

Tags: java, swing, jtable

My JTable is declared as so:

```
String[] cols = {"Name","Location"};
String[][] data = new String[][] {{"Name","Location"}};
JTable table = new JTable(data, cols);
```

So i came across a problem when trying to update my `JTable`'s data... I'm suppose to be adding a new row to the table. Here is my code for that:

```
data = new String[][] {{"Name","Location"}{"Name1","Location1"}};
DefaultTableModel dm = (DefaultTableModel)(table.getModel());
dm.fireTableDataChanged();
```

For some reason i get an error on the Line:

```
DefaultTableModel dm = (DefaultTableModel)(table.getModel());
```

The error shown is...

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JTable$1 cannot be cast to javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel
at client.pages.ClientPage.update(ClientPage.java:171)
```

Line 171 of my ClientPage.java is the above line of code that i said the error is on.

Anyone know why its doing this?

```
table.getModel(); //Suppose to return TabelModel not JTable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`table.getModel()` isn't returning a `JTable`, it's returning an [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) in `JTable` that extends `TableModel`.  Therefore, `table.getModel()` is indeed returning the correct class type.

The error occurs, however, because you try to cast this anonymous table model to `DefaultTableModel`, which is another subclass of `TableModel`, but is not the type being returned by `table.getModel()`.

To fix this, simply treat the table model as the interface type `TableModel`; don't assume it's a `DefaultTableModel`.

Answer (score 3):

Start by taking a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and the [JavaDocs for `DefaultTabelModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html)

You should change the way you are creating the table and model to something more like...

```
String[] cols = {"Name","Location"};
String[][] data = new String[][] {{"Name","Location"}};
JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(date, cols));
```

`JTable(Object[][], Object[])` actually uses it's own implementation of a the `TableModel`

Next, change....

```
data = new String[][] {{"Name","Location"}{"Name1","Location1"}};
DefaultTableModel dm = (DefaultTableModel)(table.getModel());
dm.fireTableDataChanged();
```

to something more like...

```
data = new String[][] {{"Name","Location"}{"Name1","Location1"}};
DefaultTableModel dm = (DefaultTableModel)(table.getModel());
dm.fireTableDataChanged();
```

to something more like...

```
data = new String[] {"Name1","Location1"};
DefaultTableModel dm = (DefaultTableModel)(table.getModel());
dm.addRow(data);
```